# Default seekbar displays weird; thumb floats above seekbar

Tags: android

I've tried changing margin settings for every item in the activity, but this problem persists:

Apparently I don't have the required rep to post images, so screenshot here: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/i5VUcPbVGwxOLc8TEjedKf71rd-Gd83gxbHnJBkd_MY?feat=directlink

The thumb portion of the seekbar floats above the progress portion.  Here's the XML:

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/kessilBrightText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Brightness"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/LargeText" />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/kessilBrightSeek"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/kessilBrightText"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/kessilColorText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/LargeText" />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/kessilColorSeek"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/showSettings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_outline"
                        android:onClick="showSettings"
                        android:text="Settings" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/playButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_outline"
                        android:onClick="playorstopScene"
                        android:text="Play Scene" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_bg" />


                            <com.pheelicks.visualizer.VisualizerView
            android:id="@+id/visualizerView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Can anyone offer a fix for this?  I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project in Eclipse several times.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried layouting of your seekbars without using `layout_weight` for them but just using `wrap_content` for their `layout_height` attribute?

Comment: That fixes it...thanks!  I had tried that before, but I must have still had the wieght attribute in there.  Weird effect that had...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your seekbar `layout_height` should be greater than zero. Use `wrap_content`, There doesn't appear to be a reason why you need to set weights for such a standard layout. Reconsider you layout structure in general.